# How to get one pyqt5 window instead of two small QInputDialong windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My code does exactly what I want it to,  generates a random password from int inputs through QInputDialog.  But instead of getting two small pop-up boxes I want to get one main window that has the QInputDialog fields with the buttons on one window.  How can I achieve this?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
import random

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Password Generator')
        self.setGeometry(100,100, 400, 400)
        self.num_pass()
        self.length_pass()
        self.execute()
        self.show()
        
    def num_pass(self):
        self.num_value, okPressed = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Password Amount:","Number:", 0, 1, 50, 1)
        if okPressed:
            print(self.num_value)

    def length_pass(self):
        self.len_value, okPressed = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Password Length: ","Length:", 0, 1, 50, 1)
        if okPressed:
            print(self.len_value)
            
    def execute(self):
        char = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_,./?'
        number = self.num_value
        length = self.len_value
        for password in range(self.num_value):
            passwords = ''
            for chars in range(self.len_value):
                passwords += random.choice(char)
            print(passwords)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can simply write your own password dialog.

Comment: You can add a horizontal layout, and insert a QButton and its 2 QInputDialog. And connect your button to the execute() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a horizontal layout, and insert a QButton and its 2 QInputDialog. And connect your button to the execute() method.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
import random


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Password Generator')
        self.setGeometry(100,100, 400, 400)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Press")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.execute)
        self.dialog1 = QInputDialog()
        self.dialog1.setOption(QInputDialog.NoButtons)
        self.dialog2 = QInputDialog()
        self.dialog2.setOption(QInputDialog.NoButtons)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dialog1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dialog2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def execute(self):
        char = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_,./?'
        number_v = int(self.dialog1.textValue()) #.getInt(self, "Password Amount:","Number:", 0, 1, 50, 1)
        length_v = int(self.dialog2.textValue()) #.getInt(self, "Password Length: ","Length:", 0, 1, 50, 1)
        for password in range(number_v):
            passwords = ''
            for chars in range(length_v):
                passwords += random.choice(char)
            print(passwords)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This is working more or less how I want it too!